# Import and require issue with react- can't read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've been struggling with getting my react project started.  I'm using react with babel, webpack, and a webpack dev server to quickly prototype.

First off, I can't get the import functions to work.  I tried working around this by swapping from import ES6 syntax to Node's require syntax, which seemed to fix an issue of "import" not being recognized ("can't find token import").  I don't really know where to begin troubleshooting this and was looking to be pointed in the right way if possible.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
    {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

My original code looks like:

```
const React = require('react').default;
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

//Components
const MainTable = require('./app/components/input_table/maintable').default;
const ButtonMenu = require('./app/components/button_menu/buttonmenu').default;

//App Logic
const onUndoAction = require('./app/undo').default;
const onRedoAction = require('./app/redo').default;
const onInputChange = require('./app/input').default;


class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      //properties
      super(props);
      this.props.inputId = 0


      //state
      this.state = {

        gridState: [
          {
          rows: 2,
          columns: 1,
          type:"cell"
          }
        ],

        cellValues: [{
          cellId: 0,
          cellValue: "first",
          type:"value"
        }],
        undo: [{rows: 2, columns: 1, type: "cell"},
        {cellId: 0, cellValue: "first", type:"value"}],
        redo: ["empty"],
      }
... additional code omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your babel setup in order to transpile es6 code.

Follow these steps for webpack: https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Comment: An excellent, very helpful link sir!  I found my issue and fixed it by following the installation instructions for webpack.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that your module loaders are not set up properly, usually when imports dont work its the module loaders setup from my expirience. Hope it helps